# NotePad++ Replacing Text Between 2 Consecutive Words

Tags: notepad++, regex

Scenario:
I'm trying to come up with a regular expression in a file that contains similar chunks, it's basically PGN Files.

Every Chunk Starts With
[Event "

..and ents at

(1/2-1/2|1-0|0-1)

the pipe | symbol means there's only one value between parenthesis, either 1/2-1/2 or 1-0 or 0-1

Problem:
I want to come up with regular expression that will search for 1/2-1/2 and then go upward and find "[Event " and select all that Chunk.

So considering These 3 Chunks

```
[Event "Chess"]
[Date "2016"]
[White "Caruana,F"]
[Black "Onischuk,Al"]
[Result "1-0"]

1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5 a6 4.Ba4 Nf6 5.O-O Bc5 6.c3 b5 7.Bc2 d5 8.a4 dxe4
9.axb5 Bg4 10.bxc6 exf3 11.gxf3 Be6 12.Ra5 Qd6 13.f4 e4 14.d4 exd3 15.Qxd3 O-O
16.Qxd6 Bxd6 17.Rd1 Bg4 18.Rd4 Bf3 19.Ba4 Rfe8 20.Be3 Ne4 21.Bd1 Bxd1 22.Rxd1 Rab8
23.Nd2 Rxb2 24.Nxe4 Rxe4 25.Re5 Rxe3 26.fxe3 Rb8 27.Ra5 Kf8 28.c4  1-0

[Event "Chess"]
[Date "2016"]
[White "Shabalov,A"]
[Black "Onischuk,Al"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]

1.d4 Nf6 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 d5 4.Nf3 Be7 5.e3 O-O 6.Bd3 dxc4 7.Bxc4 c5 8.O-O b6
9.Qe2 Bb7 10.dxc5 Bxc5 11.e4 Nbd7 12.Bf4 Nh5 13.Bg5 Be7 14.Be3 Nhf6 15.Rfd1 Qb8
16.Nd4 Rd8 17.f3 Ne5 18.Bb3 Nc6 19.Nxc6 Rxd1+ 20.Rxd1 Bxc6 21.Nb5 Qe5 22.Na3 Qc7
23.Rc1 Rc8 24.Qa6 Qd7 25.Rd1 Qc7 26.Rc1 Qd7 27.Rd1 Qc7 28.Rc1 Qd7 29.Rd1 Qc7
30.Rc1  1/2-1/2

[Event "Chess"]
[Date "2016"]
[White "Onischuk,Al"]
[Black "Akobian,V"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]

1.d4 d5 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 Nf6 4.Bg5 Be7 5.Nf3 O-O 6.Qc2 h6 7.Bh4 b6 8.cxd5 Nxd5
9.Nxd5 exd5 10.Bxe7 Qxe7 11.Rc1 c5 12.dxc5 Bg4 13.e3 Bxf3 14.gxf3 Rc8 15.Qd2 Rxc5
16.Rxc5 Qxc5 17.Bg2 Nd7 18.O-O Rc8 19.Rd1 Nf6 20.f4 Qc2 21.Bxd5 Nxd5 22.Qxd5 Qxb2
23.Qd7 Rc1 24.Rxc1 Qxc1+ 25.Kg2 Qc4 26.Qxa7 Qe4+ 27.Kg3 Qg6+ 28.Kf3 Qh5+
29.Kg2 Qg4+ 30.Kf1 Qd1+ 31.Kg2  1/2-1/2
```

So If I enter that expression, (while search starts at bottom, it should only find & select 3rd chunk like this

```
[Event "Chess"]
[Date "2016"]
[White "Onischuk,Al"]
[Black "Akobian,V"]
[Result "1/2-1/2"]

1.d4 d5 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 Nf6 4.Bg5 Be7 5.Nf3 O-O 6.Qc2 h6 7.Bh4 b6 8.cxd5 Nxd5
9.Nxd5 exd5 10.Bxe7 Qxe7 11.Rc1 c5 12.dxc5 Bg4 13.e3 Bxf3 14.gxf3 Rc8 15.Qd2 Rxc5
16.Rxc5 Qxc5 17.Bg2 Nd7 18.O-O Rc8 19.Rd1 Nf6 20.f4 Qc2 21.Bxd5 Nxd5 22.Qxd5 Qxb2
23.Qd7 Rc1 24.Rxc1 Qxc1+ 25.Kg2 Qc4 26.Qxa7 Qe4+ 27.Kg3 Qg6+ 28.Kf3 Qh5+
29.Kg2 Qg4+ 30.Kf1 Qd1+ 31.Kg2  1/2-1/2
```

...then when I click find next, It should find 7 select 2nd chunk.

So the 2 Words to search between are
1. [Event "
2.  1/2-1/2

Please can someone help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit according to reformate**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\[Event (?:(?!\[Event)[\s\S])+1/2-1/2(?!"\])`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\[Event     : literally [Event 
(?:         : start non capture group
  (?!       : start negative look ahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we don't have [Event after
    \[Event : literally [Event
  )         : end look ahead
  [\s\S]    : any character, space or not space
)+          : group appears 1 or more times
1/2-1/2     : literally 1/2-1/2
(?!"\])     : negative look ahead, zero-length assertion that make sure we don't have "] after
```

This is matching block 2 and block 3 in the given example.

Comment: @Sollosa: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: @Sollosa: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: done it, It was due on me for real.

Comment: it does, the only glitch I now face is, I want to select one line break before the expression, and one line break after it. I hope you can suggest what to add.

Comment: @Sollosa: Just add `\R` before `\[Event` and after the last look ahead, `\R\[Event.......(?!"\])\R` you may also remove the look ahead: `\R\[Event.......1/2-1/2\R`